# Python Panda's row selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried doing some searching, but I'm having troubles finding what I specifically need. I currently have this.

```
location = 'Location'
data = pd.read_csv('testbook.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
search = 'OR' # This will be replaced with an input 
row = (df[df.eq(search).any(1)])
print(row)
Location = row.at[0, location]
print(Location)
```

This outputs this

row print out

```
       Location City  Price  Etc
0       FL      OR    50     123
```

Location print out

```
FL
```

[image: csv info]

this is the CSV information that it's pull the data from.
My main question and issue is what I'm trying to find out is at this specific line of code

```
Location = row.at[0, location]
```

for Location what I'm trying to do and see if possible is in the brackets [0, location].

I want it to automate in the future since for example if I need to find instead of 'OR' I need to find what data is in 'OR1'. The issue is that the [0] is related to the Row # hence this(this is the entire df).

```
  Location City  Price   Etc
0       FL   OR     50   123
1      FL1  OR1    501  1231
2      FL2  OR2    502  1232
```

I would have to manually change the code every single time which of course is unfeasible with what I'm trying to accomplish.

My main question is, how do I pull specific row numbers all the way on the left and take that output and make it a variable that I can input anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what you are looking for but this is my best guess

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Location':['FL', 'FL1', 'FL2'], 
        'City': ['OR', 'OR1', 'OR2'], 
        'Price':[50, 501, 502],
        'Etc': [123,1231,1232]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Given search term -> find location
search = 'OR'
# Outputs 'FL'
df['Location'][df['City'] == search].any()
```

Comment: This may have solved my problem. I'll have to double check, but yea I wasn't sure how to make my question more clear.

Comment: Let me know if there is any issues. It helps if you keep things concise. "This is my code, this is my dataset, this is what I want, here are my errors". In this case you are looking for location from a given search city. Welcome to stack overflow!